# YouTube AdSense stopped paying - what to do?

Tags: google-adsense, youtube

A few months go I placed AdSense ads for YouTube on the video that appears on this [Android app landing page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.problemio&hl=en).

For a while things went ok, but then suddenly any of the clicks and views stopped generating cash. I was still getting YouTube reports of the number of ad clicks, but they were all worth nothing.

Now I am starting a YouTube channel and would like to get my YouTube AdSense to good standing. Would anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

AdSense doesn't give you any sort of control over what they pay.

Your only recourse is to keep another ad network on hand and use them when AdSense does not seem to be performing.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, AdSense for YouTube has a very low CPC... Mine has decreased to less than 50% in the last month. For me it is not even worthy thinking about YouTube anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the clicks are from unique IP. Google does not count clicks coming from same single IP or group of IPs.

Comment: why would they be the same ip if the clicks are coming from different users?

Comment: It is never said that the different user are viewing the AdSense neither does the AdSense gives such kind of report